# Call activity function from another activity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got two activities A and B, and i would like to call activity B function from activity A. How can i do it?  So i would like to call this function in activity A.

```
 public void LoadXMLData()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("xmlEXAMPLE.persons.xml");
        ObservableCollection<Person> PersonInformation;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
        PersonInformation = (ObservableCollection<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        MyListView.ItemsSource = PersonInformation;

    }
```

Comment: Does the `MyListView` is present on both activities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your project xamarin.forms or xamarin.android ?

The easiest way is to set the activity to global static.

If your project is xamarin.forms,you could set your `page` to `static` :

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public static Page1 Instance;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }

    //here is the method you want call in Page2
    public void DoInPage2()
    {
     .......
    }
}
```

then in Page2 you could call like `Page1.Instance.DoInPage2();`

if your project is xamarin.android,you could also set the `activity` to `static`

```
public class ActivityA: Activity
{
    public static ActivityA Instance;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(....);
        Instance = this;
    }

    //here is the method you want call in ActivityB
    public void CallInActivityB()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

then you could call it in ActivityB like `ActivityA.Instance.CallInActivityB();`